# Proof: in any set of n rational numbers there is a no mean in between permutation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

A permutation of n rational numbers is called "beautiful" if the mean of no two rational numbers is in the middle of them. Using induction, prove that in any set of n rational of numbers, we can find a beautiful permutation.

I tried solving the question using strong induction but i can only prove this for natural numbers by dividing the set into even and odd numbers. But i don't know how to do it for rational numbers.

EDIT: this is what I've thought of so far but it seems way too simple to be correct.

Inductive step : assuming that the above statement is true for n rational numbers,we must show that it is also true for n+1 rational numbers.
If we add one rational number to the end of the set, check from the end if there is a number with which the added number produces a mean which already exists in between the two numbers and insert the added number between that number and the mean. If we repeat this algorithm until we reach the start of the set that would give us the permutation we want.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? What do you know about the topic? What progress have you made on solving the problem? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I edited in all the info i had. @Gerry Myerson

Comment: You can multiply everything by the LCM of the denominators so that you turn the problem back into a problem about integers.

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot. @Jaap Scherphuis

Comment: Now that i think more about it, my proof works only on sets with the same number of odd and even numbers. But there is no such guarantee in this question @Jaap Scherphuis

Comment: That's all the info you had, Sara? You don't know where the problem came from? Where you first saw it? On a homework assignment? On a take-home exam? As part of a contest? As part of an application to a math program somewhere? Please, Sara, level with us.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Note a quite similar question at [prove that there is a permutation of n distinctive rational numbers that the average of two numbers is not between them](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3885381/602049) was just asked. I've requested more info from the OP, similar to what you ask in your comment.

Comment: it's a university homework assignment. And We just finished Induction. @Gerry Myerson

Comment: And you have the teacher's permission to ask for help on the web?

Comment: It is encouraged actually but i don't see how these new info is going to help anyone solve this problem easier. @Gerry Myerson

Comment: It may help people decide whether they want to help anyone solve this problem.