# Minimum number of distances determined by $n$ points on a plane

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Set $S$ is the set of the distances between any two dots in a panel. Prove that given $202$ dots in a panel, the set will have at least $11$ members.

I tried using pigeonhole principle. Every three dots can form a equilateral triangle but adding a fourth dot will definitely produce another distance. But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Where does this problem come from, please? (We've had this conversation before, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3884647/proof-in-any-set-of-n-rational-numbers-there-is-a-no-mean-in-between-permutatio)

Comment: University homework assignment. And yes we are allowed to look and ask for solutions online@Gerry Myerson

Comment: OK. It would be better if you'd be upfront on these matters in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This concerns a famous result of P.Erdos, later generalized by others. We in fact have :

> If $f(n)$ denotes the minimum number of distances determined by $n$ points on a plane, then $$
> \sqrt{n - \frac 34} - \frac12 \leq f(n)
> $$

Proof of the lower bound : The $n$ points can be enclosed in a convex shape $P$, called the *convex hull* of the points. This can be proved using linear algebra, for example, and can be shown in this case to be a convex polygon which has vertices made up from these points.

Let $P_1$ be any one of the points lying on $P$ as well. Consider the distances given by $P_1P_i, i=2,3,...,n$, and let $K = |\{|P_1P_i|, i=2,3,...,n\}|$.

If $N$ is the maximum number of times a distance occurs, we must have $KN \geq n-1$, obviously i.e. $f(n) \geq \frac{n-1}{N}$.

Furthermore, if a distance $r$ occurs $N$ times, then these points occuring $n$ times must lie in the same *semicircle* of radius $r$ around $P_1$, since these points lie on one side of $P_1$ because $P_1$ is on the convex hull.

It is easy to see that these points among themselves have at least $N-1$ different distances (draw a diagram and see this). Therefore $f(n) \geq N-1$.

Thus, *for any $N$* we have $f(n) \geq \max\{N-1 , \frac{n-1}{N}\}$. It is easy to minimize this over all $n>N >0$ and obtain the expression given.

It is even easier to obtain a rough upper bound, but remarkably there are better lower bounds than the above. One of these is $Cn^{\frac 57}$ for a fixed constant $C>0$, which I believe is the best.

Comment: Thank you very much. Does this mean that the question should actually be to prove that the minimum distance is more than 12? And how should I determine C?

Comment: "How should I determine $C$"  : It comes in a difficult paper, so I don't think you will be able to derive it just like that, and it is too strong for the question anyway. Also, the question is to prove that if you take $202$ points and take the set of all distances between them, then the number of possible different numbers that you get is at least $11$. From my logic above, you get that it is at least $\sqrt{201.5} - \frac 12$, which is more than $12$.